npm run dev runs into [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]
I try to start a website frontend but when runnin npm run dev and try to access localhost:3000 I get the following error message:
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'
I use these versions in the project
PS C:\projectpath> node -v v20.12.2 PS C:\projectpath> npm -v 10.6.0 PS C:\projectpath> npx tsc Version 5.4.5
I tried some solutions like changing to an lts version of node or start vs code in admin mode, but the error keeps appearing even though I use a stable version of node.
The issue is that the format the URL is in is not supported by the default esm loader. But it doesn't give me information what the current format is, where I can find it or where I could upgrade the esm loader to support the current format.
